# Having some fun - what is a good way to include a secret key functionality and fire the KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

To keep myself interested, I try to put little Easter Eggs in my projects (mostly to amuse myself).  I've seen some websites where you can type a series of letters "aswzaswz" and you get a "secret function" - how would I achieve this in C#?

I've assigned a "secret function" in the past by using modifier keys

```
        bool showFunThing = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control;
```

but wanted to get a bit more secretive (without the modifier keys)  I just wanted the form to detect a certain word typed without any input ... I've built a method that I think should do it:

```
    private StringBuilder _pressedKeys = new StringBuilder();

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        const string kWord = "fun";
        char letter = (char)e.KeyValue;
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(letter))
        { return; }
        _pressedKeys.Append(letter);
        if (_pressedKeys.Length == kWord.Length)
        {
            if (_pressedKeys.ToString().ToLower() == kWord)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fun");
                _pressedKeys.Clear();
            }
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

Now I need to wire it up but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to raise the event in the form designer ... I've tried this:

```
    this.KeyDown +=new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);
```

and a couple of variations on this but I'm missing something because it won't fire (or compile).  It tells me that the OnKeyDown method is expecting a certain signature but I've got other methods like this where I haven't specified arguments.

I fear that I may have got myself confused so I am turning to SO for help ... anyone?

**EDIT: The ProcessCmdKey seems to be the way that works with the following:**

```
    private StringBuilder _pressedKeys = new StringBuilder();
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        const string kWord = "fun";
        char letter = (char)keyData;
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(letter))
        {return true;}
        _pressedKeys.Append(letter);
        if (_pressedKeys.Length == kWord.Length)
        {
         if (_pressedKeys.ToString().ToLower() == kWord)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fun");
                _pressedKeys.Clear();
            }
            _pressedKeys.Clear();
        }
     return true;
    }
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.P|Keys.Control))
    {
        //do my prank
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

This will fire when you press CTRL + P.

refer: [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)

> This method is called during message preprocessing to handle command
>   keys. Command keys are keys that always take precedence over regular
>   input keys. Examples of command keys include accelerators and menu
>   shortcuts. The method must return true to indicate that it has
>   processed the command key

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding a virtual method, so you do not need to handle the KeyDown event. If you debug, you should hit a breakpoint in you overriden method if something calls the virtual method.

Are you sure you are overriding the correct method in the correct class though? Just a thought.

Comment: I had a little test but it never fired ... that's why I thought I needed the bit in the form designer ...